# How to create a table inside of recently created database with dynamic sql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I want to populate a set of tables and procedures into new databases programmatically.

Then I prepared a Initialize Script and I will use it inside a procedure who must created new databases.

I tried with a simple example and didn't work:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROCEDURETOREPLICATECOMMONSCHEMA
    @databaseName NVARCHAR(40)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sqlCreation NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @sqlCreation = '
        USE MASTER;

        EXEC(''CREATE DATABASE ' + @databaseName + ''');

        EXEC(''USE ' + @databaseName + ''');

        CREATE TABLE Testing
        (
            TestPk int,
            TestDescription nvarchar(80)
        );
    ';

    PRINT @sqlCreation;
    EXEC sp_executesql @sqlCreation;
END
GO
```

When I execute this procedure, it creates the table `Testing` inside master database instead of `TestDatabase1`.

```
EXEC PROCEDURETOREPLICATECOMMONSCHEMA 'TestDatabase1'
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

First create the database, then create the table (two separate statements):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROCEDURETOREPLICATECOMMONSCHEMA
    @databaseName NVARCHAR(40)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sqlCreation NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @sqlCreation = 'USE MASTER;
                        EXEC(''CREATE DATABASE ' + @databaseName + ''');';

    EXEC sp_executesql @sqlCreation;   

    SET @sqlCreation = 'EXEC(''USE ' + @databaseName + ''');

        CREATE TABLE ' + @databaseName + '.dbo.Testing
        (
            TestPk int,
            TestDescription nvarchar(80)
        );';

    EXEC sp_executesql @sqlCreation;
END
GO
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please make use of the below code. Its working fine with SQL Server 2012.

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE PROCEDURETOREPLICATECOMMONSCHEMA
    @databaseName NVARCHAR(40)
AS
BEGIN
   BEGIN
    EXEC('USE MASTER;CREATE DATABASE ' + @databaseName + ';')
    EXEC('CREATE TABLE ' + @databaseName + '.dbo.Testing(TestPk int,TestDescription nvarchar(80));')
END
END
GO
```